# add a string to a textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a string to a text area which has value may be grater than 2 lines. May be it is an ASCII ART but my main question is that how can I post ASCII art to a textarea? I am using jQuery and following codes: If I am using specific button means contain a class than what will be the code.

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("input:text").val(" (██)
__________(█)_______________██████
_________(███)___________ █████████
________(█████)________████████████
______ (███████)______ (░░░░░░░░░░░)
_____(█████████)_____(░░░░█░░█░░░░)
____(██░░░░░░░██)___ (░░(░░░●░░░)░░░)
_____▒░░█░░█░░▒____ (░░░(░░◡░░)░░░░)
____▒░░░░░░░░░░▒___ (░░░░░░░░░░░░░)
____▒░░█░░░█░░░▒___██(░░░░░░░░░)██
____▒░░░███░░░░▒___███(░░░░░░)████
_____▒░░░░░░░░▒___████████████████
_____██░░░░░░██___████████████████
____▒▒███████▒▒___███ █████████ ███
___▒░░░█████░░░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░▒░░░███░░░▒░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░░▒░░███░░▒░░▒_ ███ █████████ ███
_▒░░░▒░███░▒░░░▒_ (░░) █████████_(░░)
__▒░░▒░███░▒░░▒_______█████████__(██)
_▒▒▒▒░░███░░▒▒▒▒_____█████████__/▓▓▓\
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒__(░░░░)_(░░░░)▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
__▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒______████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>

    <button>Set the value of the input field</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

But it does not show me anything to me. Please help me out.

Comment: drop it in a text file and load by ajax ...[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tdJaLjG2EXVSW2NCNzF). No cross browser or escaping issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another [moderately well supported](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_strings) option for multiline strings is to use the new [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Also, normal text inputs don't support multiple lines. A `<textarea>` does, however.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("textarea").val(` (██)
__________(█)_______________██████
_________(███)___________ █████████
________(█████)________████████████
______ (███████)______ (░░░░░░░░░░░)
_____(█████████)_____(░░░░█░░█░░░░)
____(██░░░░░░░██)___ (░░(░░░●░░░)░░░)
_____▒░░█░░█░░▒____ (░░░(░░◡░░)░░░░)
____▒░░░░░░░░░░▒___ (░░░░░░░░░░░░░)
____▒░░█░░░█░░░▒___██(░░░░░░░░░)██
____▒░░░███░░░░▒___███(░░░░░░)████
_____▒░░░░░░░░▒___████████████████
_____██░░░░░░██___████████████████
____▒▒███████▒▒___███ █████████ ███
___▒░░░█████░░░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░▒░░░███░░░▒░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░░▒░░███░░▒░░▒_ ███ █████████ ███
_▒░░░▒░███░▒░░░▒_ (░░) █████████_(░░)
__▒░░▒░███░▒░░▒_______█████████__(██)
_▒▒▒▒░░███░░▒▒▒▒_____█████████__/▓▓▓\
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒__(░░░░)_(░░░░)▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
__▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒______████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Name:
  <textarea></textarea>
</p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify a multi-line string in JavaScript, but it will be ugly. For example:

```
// This has 3 lines
var s =
    "abc\n" +
    "def\n" + 
    "ghi";
```

An alternative solution is to put a multi-line string in hidden HTML code, then extract it using jQuery on the DOM:

```
<pre id="my-art" style="display:none">here is my
multi-line ascii art
snowman or other graphic</pre>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val(
            $("#my-art").text()
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to support an ES6 feature, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("textarea").val(`
                             (██)
__________(█)_______________██████
_________(███)___________ █████████
________(█████)________████████████
______ (███████)______ (░░░░░░░░░░░)
_____(█████████)_____(░░░░█░░█░░░░)
____(██░░░░░░░██)___ (░░(░░░●░░░)░░░)
_____▒░░█░░█░░▒____ (░░░(░░◡░░)░░░░)
____▒░░░░░░░░░░▒___ (░░░░░░░░░░░░░)
____▒░░█░░░█░░░▒___██(░░░░░░░░░)██
____▒░░░███░░░░▒___███(░░░░░░)████
_____▒░░░░░░░░▒___████████████████
_____██░░░░░░██___████████████████
____▒▒███████▒▒___███ █████████ ███
___▒░░░█████░░░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░▒░░░███░░░▒░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░░▒░░███░░▒░░▒_ ███ █████████ ███
_▒░░░▒░███░▒░░░▒_ (░░) █████████_(░░)
__▒░░▒░███░▒░░▒_______█████████__(██)
_▒▒▒▒░░███░░▒▒▒▒_____█████████__/▓▓▓\
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒__(░░░░)_(░░░░)▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
__▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒______████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)`
        )});
    });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/b5yndog7/) is a fiddle with how to implement in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Hatchet's code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("textarea").width(360);
    $("textarea").height(360);
    $("textarea").val(` (██)
__________(█)_______________██████
_________(███)___________ █████████
________(█████)________████████████
______ (███████)______ (░░░░░░░░░░░)
_____(█████████)_____(░░░░█░░█░░░░)
____(██░░░░░░░██)___ (░░(░░░●░░░)░░░)
_____▒░░█░░█░░▒____ (░░░(░░◡░░)░░░░)
____▒░░░░░░░░░░▒___ (░░░░░░░░░░░░░)
____▒░░█░░░█░░░▒___██(░░░░░░░░░)██
____▒░░░███░░░░▒___███(░░░░░░)████
_____▒░░░░░░░░▒___████████████████
_____██░░░░░░██___████████████████
____▒▒███████▒▒___███ █████████ ███
___▒░░░█████░░░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░▒░░░███░░░▒░▒__███ █████████ ███
_▒░░▒░░███░░▒░░▒_ ███ █████████ ███
_▒░░░▒░███░▒░░░▒_ (░░) █████████_(░░)
__▒░░▒░███░▒░░▒_______█████████__(██)
_▒▒▒▒░░███░░▒▒▒▒_____█████████__/▓▓▓\
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒__(░░░░)_(░░░░)▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒___████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
_▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒____ ████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓)
__▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒______████__████▓▓▓▓▓▓)`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Name:
  <textarea></textarea>
</p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
```